# Analisar emails com R

Tags: r

Gostaria de saber por favor se há algum pacote no R que faça text mining para emails do outlook, para que possa filtrar emails por palavras chave, ou por algum tipo de argumento, extraindo informações relevantes e ignorando os demais emails.

Answer (score 0):

O R tem pacotes que lhe permitem analisar documentos de texto para a realização de processamento dos documentos, como filtragem e extração de informações. Entretanto, as APIs, não soh de R, como Python, Java, etc, são bem "baixo nível".

Posso estar errado, mas observando a sua pergunta acredito que vc seja iniciante na questão de text mining. Enfim, existe o processo de KDD que orienta o pesquisador em como analisar documentos.

No caso, acredito que vc vá precisar extrair os emails do Outlook para documentos de texto. Fazer a limpagem e processamento dos dados.
Aplicar técnicas básicas de text mining, como remoção de stop word, TF-IDF, etc.

Após criar um dicionário de palavras, e aplicar uim regex em todos os documentos, para localizar as palavras. Quando vc escreve "extraindo informações relevantes" pode significar muitas coisas.

Como a pergunta não tem nenhum código e ainda sugere que vc eh muito iniciante, recomendo fazer algum curso na área, como o Datacamp que é super prático.